# Given Two non-colinear vectors, what is the radius of a pair of congruent circles that are externally tangent to each other and one given vector each?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Due to character restrictions the title terminology might not be quite right, by vector I effectively mean a given point on a given line that the circles are to be tangent to.

It feels like this should have some elegant solution, but I was unable to work though it with (free) wolfram alpha. I believe the answer should be able to be in the from of the radius in terms of x, y, and angle. Might also be able to be in terms of distance between givens, angle1, angle2.

[image]

The dotted arrow coming out of A is the first given vector and the arrow coming out of B pointing at E is the second. The large dotted circles are the circle pair we want the radius of. The rest is part of my attempts to figure out what I had to work with for solving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the given tangents meet at $T$ with an angle $\theta$ (see figure). The lines perpendicular to the tangents at $A$ and $B$ meet at $Q$ with an angle $\pi-\theta$. Set: $a=AQ$ and $b=BQ$.
The cosine rule applied to triangle $QCD$ gives then:
$$
(a-r)^2+(b-r)^2+2(a-r)(b-r)\cos\theta=4r^2,
$$
a quadratic equation which can be solved for $r$.

The case where the tangents are parallel is easier and is left to the reader.

[image]

Comment: This gets two solutions, the both circles 'inward' as you depicted and both circles 'outward' but there are two more solutions (Which I was only able to figure there was more than one solution thanks to your help) where the circles go the opposite directions from one another, which is apparently the solution I thought existed and was primarily seeking.

Comment: (I am aware my initial picture shows a solution your method would get, I got lost trying to figure it out on my own and made that model by working backwards with construction in GeoGebra and am only now realizing it isn't solving the problem I started with. That being to maximize circle radius without making the path between them extra long)

Comment: @Thk For the inward-outward solutions, it should be enough to change the sign of a radius: $$
(a-r)^2+(b+r)^2+2(a-r)(b+r)\cos\theta=4r^2.
$$